# Return database scalar value using nlog

Tags: c#, nlog

We are designing a logging mechanism using Nlog for our application. There is a common value which we need to hold in the database for particular session which is generated by Nlog. 
But here problem is we are unable to get the value if data is already existing in the table.

We are using **Logger.Log** method to send the value to database through stored procedure.

Is there any way to return the scalar value through Nlog if the data matches in the stored procedure.

We are unable to post the code due to security issues.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning a id from database with nlog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37589065/returning-a-id-from-database-with-nlog)

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved by cloned the Database Target then modified the ExecuteNonQuery() to ExecuteScalar() and used a public property to return the scalar value.